# How to integrate this kubernetes template into this helm template

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

As the title describes, I am trying to integrate this Kubernetes template into this helm template in order to run the command kubectl apply. Is there a way to integrate the two into one yaml file? Or would I have to separate the two into different files?

The kubernetes template is:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  replicas: 5
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

The Helm template is:

```
proxy:
  secretToken: 98768c9cb1e1376d335f29b778dbf6e6d9d2c44ceba4b06f17d5e7c6b53c5afc
  service:
    type: ClusterIP

imagePullSecret:
  create: true
  registry: libretextsregistry.ddns.net
  username: libretexts
  password: JVZJxTSm4wnTHVEjwkq49wy469eSS

ingress:
  enabled: true
  hosts:
    - staging.jupyter.libretexts.org
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt"
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - staging.jupyter.libretexts.org
      secretName: tls-cert

scheduling:
  userScheduler:
    enabled: false

cull:
  enabled: true
  timeout: 3600
  every: 300

singleuser:
  defaultUrl: "/lab"
  storage:
    capacity: 2G
  cpu:
    limit: 4
    guarantee: 0.5
  memory:
    limit: 7G
    guarantee: 7G
  image:
    name: libretextsregistry.ddns.net/binder-dev-libretexts-2ddefault-2denv-1cb626
    tag: "230d85d708cb6f6d1b6ba36bd2919a431eede445" # 3.3.1
  profileList:
    - display_name: "New Default Environment"
      description: "New environment with updated packages. Contains Python, R, Julia, Octave, SageMath and C++ kernels. Please report any issues to jupyterteam@ucdavis.edu."
      default: true
    - display_name: "R Studio"
      description: "Opens directly into R Studio."
      kubespawner_override:
        default_url: "/rstudio"
    - display_name: "High resource test "
      description: "Test for lots of resources"
      kubespawner_override:
        mem_limit: 32G
        mem_guarantee: 32G
        cpu_limit: 4
        cpu_guarantee: 4
  networkPolicy:
    egressAllowRules:
      privateIPs: true

hub:
  config:
    Authenticator:
      admin_users:
      - moorepants@gmail.com
      - rafeltstykket@ucdavis.edu
      allowed_users:
        # Do not remove this section. Users are permitted into the hub based on their email
        # as can be seen in the `extraConfig` section near the bottom of this chart
      - jasonmoore@ucdavis.edu
      - rafeltstykket@ucdavis.edu
    GoogleOAuthenticator:
      client_id: 988102819487-b7vs07so9qjtts93unkoc7avsdn2jiod.apps.googleusercontent.com
      client_secret: 4dI3vbpCef9K75uab_lhQRJp
      oauth_callback_url: https://staging.jupyter.libretexts.org/hub/oauth_callback
    JupyterHub:
      admin_access: true
      authenticator_class: google
  # Clone custom JupyterHub templates into a volume
  initContainers:
    - name: git-clone-templates
      image: alpine/git
      command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
      args:
        - >-
            git clone --branch=staging https://github.com/LibreTexts/jupyterhub-templates.git /tmp/jupyterhub-templates &&
            cp -r /tmp/jupyterhub-templates/templates/* /templates &&
            cp -r /tmp/jupyterhub-templates/static/* /static
      volumeMounts:
        - name: custom-templates
          mountPath: /templates
        - name: custom-templates-static
          mountPath: /static
  extraVolumes:
    - name: custom-templates
      emptyDir: {}
    - name: custom-templates-static
      emptyDir: {}
  extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: custom-templates
      mountPath: /etc/jupyterhub/templates
    - name: custom-templates-static
      mountPath: /usr/local/share/jupyterhub/static/external
  extraConfig:
    templates: |
      from jupyterhub.handlers.base import BaseHandler
      class AboutHandler(BaseHandler):
          async def get(self):
              self.write(await self.render_template("about.html"))
      class FAQHandler(BaseHandler):
          async def get(self):
              self.write(await self.render_template("faq.html"))
      c.JupyterHub.extra_handlers.extend([
          (r"about", AboutHandler),
          (r"faq", FAQHandler),
      ])
      c.JupyterHub.template_paths = ['/etc/jupyterhub/templates']
    ngshare.py: |
      c.JupyterHub.services.append({
        'name': 'ngshare',
        'url': 'http://ngshare.staging-jhub.svc.cluster.local:8080',
        'api_token': '1c29b8e60345a9f57f7c40dfc10256dad5c2de6083b3bb29c7fa8a98c79a23bb',
        'oauth_no_confirm': True})
    announcement: |
      # if you want to add an announcement onto our hub homepage / spawner pages, use the following:
      c.JupyterHub.template_vars = {'announcement': ""}
    allow-ucdavis-accounts: |
      from oauthenticator.google import GoogleOAuthenticator
      class UCDavisGoogleOAuthenticator(GoogleOAuthenticator):
          from tornado import gen
          @gen.coroutine
          def pre_spawn_start(self, user, spawner):
              auth_state = yield user.get_auth_state()
              spawner.environment = {'NB_USER':spawner.user.name, 'NB_UID':'1000'}
          def check_allowed(self, username, authentication=None):
              if not self.allowed_users:
                  return True
              if username.endswith("@ucdavis.edu"):
                  return True
              if username.endswith("@libretexts.org"):
                  return True
              if username in self.allowed_users:
                  return True
              return False
      c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = UCDavisGoogleOAuthenticator
      c.KubeSpawner.args = ['--allow-root']
```

How can I integrate the two into one yaml file?

Comment: The first file looks like an (untemplated) Kubernetes YAML file, that might be in a Helm chart's `templates/deployment.yaml`; the second is the configuration to a Helm chart, often its `values.yaml`.  How are you trying to combine these?

Comment: I'm trying to combine both of these into a single config.yaml file

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are building a Helm Chart, using the Helm Client to run the `helm install` command to deploy your application instead of `kubectl apply` would be a simple solution.

If you are for some reason unable to use the Helm Client to directly install the Chart, you can run `helm template` to generate a Kubernetes manifest from the Chart (substitute in the values), then `kubectl apply` the generated file:

`helm template ./my-chart > manifest.yaml`

`kubectl apply -f manifest.yaml`

This assumes a repo structure with a Helm Chart at the root e.g.

```
.. repository root
.
|-- my-chart/
|    |-- Chart.yaml
|    |-- values.yaml
|    `-- templates/
|        |-- deployment.yaml
|        `-- ...
`-- ...
```

Where the two files listed are assumed to be `templates/deployment.yaml` and `values.yaml` as David suggested.